# How to hide flashes on a touch screen?

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, air, touch

I'm developing an Adobe Air application for Windows which makes use of a touch screen. When I touch the screen, both on the Windows desktop and within my app, there is a circular flash at the touch point.

[image: The flashing touch point]

How do I disable this, so that there is no visible indication of the touch point, other than that provided by my app? Is does not seem possible to disable this in the Windows touch settings, and there is no mention of visual feedback that I can find in the air API.

Comment: For that, try [from lenovo.com](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht071573?tabName=Solutions) and [from hp.com](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems-Software-Recovery/Removing-cursor-ripple-effects-from-Windows-7-using-a/m-p/1877021#M58240) and [this](http://forum.wacom.eu/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=12141).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a hardware issue, not AIR or AS3 related. So as akmozo suggests, try looking to the screen manufacturer for instructions on how to disable touch markers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...it worked for me on a win7 system.

> OK,--Click Start, type in gpedit.msc and hit enter. --Click through
>   User Configuration --Administrative Templates -- Windows Components --
>   Tablet PC -- Cursors. --Double click on "Turn off pen feedback" and
>   select Enabled to enable the filter that turns off the ripple. Do this
>   not just for User Configuration but repeat the process for Computer
>   Configuration to make sure it is disabled for everyone using the
>   workstation

The link [here](http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-disable-ripple-effect-using-windows-7-with-Wacom-tablet).

Comment: Please quote the important parts of the linked answer in the answer, as the answer may be of no use if the link is removed.

Comment: OK,--Click Start, type in gpedit.msc and hit enter.
--Click through User Configuration --Administrative Templates -- Windows Components -- Tablet PC -- Cursors.
--Double click on "Turn off pen feedback" and select Enabled to enable the filter that turns off the ripple.


Do this not just for User Configuration but repeat the process for Computer Configuration to make sure it is disabled for everyone using the workstation.